# protobuf message parsing issue for approximately 50MB size

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

We have encountered protobuf message parsing issue for approximately 50MB size.
Although I extended the related maximum definition to handle big size output

```
cout<<"Before parseFromArray"<<endl;
pb.ParseFromArray(ptr, msgLen);  //ptr is the char* pointer,msgLen is the length of char buffer
cout<<"After parseFromArray"<<endl;
```

The code is stuck or hanged at the parseFromArray stage.
Is there any way I can debug this ?

Comment: you could inspect what is stored in `ptr` before trying to parse it. Btw nobody else is able to debug it given the lack of details you provide.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and forcing a break when it is hanging?